# How to store homepage in cache in laravel 4

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4

I am new in laravel and php. I am developing a magazine site with laravel 4. I want to store home page in laravel cache . But In my homepage , there are many queries . Please see details below.:

My HomepageController index method:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('homepage');
}
```

My Query Helper Function which is used for post by category in my Homepage:

```
 public static function cat_post($category, $limit)
    {
        $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category)
            {
                $q->where('category_slug', 'like', $category);

            })->with('categories')->take($limit)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        return $posts;
    }
```

In My homepage.blade.php , I used this helper function many times. like below:

```
<?php $national = Helper::cat_post('national', 3); ?>

@foreach ($national as $post)
    {{ Helper::img_src($post) }}
    <h4><a href="{{ Helper::post_link($post) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h4>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Now i want to put homepage in cache and when new post created, then delete old homepage from cache and store new one.

Please help me. Is it possible ?????

Answer (score 0):

To store a value in cache you can use [Laravel's Cache](http://laravel.com/docs/cache):

```
public function index()
{
    return Cache::rememberForever('homepageCache', function()
    {
        return View::make('homepage');
    });
}
```

This snipped tries to retrieve a cached version of `View::make('homepage')` and otherwise creates it.

Every time a *post* is created, updated or deleted you need to invalide your *homepageCache*:

```
Cache::forget('homepageCache');
```